# Slater constraint qualification: Does equality constraint imply Slater fails?

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

Does equality constraint always imply that the [Slater condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition) fails. For example, consider the optimization problem:
$$\min_{X\in S^n_+} \ tr(AX)$$
$$s.t.\ XX^T=I$$

Since we can't have
$$XX^T-I \succ 0$$ and $$-XX^T+I\succ0$$ does that mean Slater fails? Under what condition,  equality constraint implies Slater fails?

Comment: Where's the SDP?

Comment: Feel free to replace the constraint with a linear one.

Comment: Wouldn't that produce a linear program?

Comment: Add PSD constraints to feasibility set.

Comment: It is only the nonlinear constraints which must be satisfied with strict inequality in Slater's condition. Linear equality constraints are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slater constraint qualification pertains to convex optimization problems. Nonlinear equality constraints are non-convex, except in trivial cases such as $x^2 = 0$. Your constraint $XX^T = I$ is non-convex, so your optimization problem is non-convex and the Slater constraint qualification does not apply.

As mentioned, the Slater constraint qualification only "restricts" nonlinear constraints, and is not applied to linear constraints (equality or inequality).

Comment: So for convex problem with linear equality constraints, does slater’s condition always holds?

Comment: @one use That is correct. It "trivially' holds.